# React Native socket.io keeps saying

Tags: react-native, socket.io

My react native keeps saying [Error: websocket error]. I have follow some tutorial on the web but still can not get it working. Anyone know if there is a syntax error or somethig to change from this code?

This is my full react code that i follow from this topic [socket io not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724385/react-native-and-socket-io-node-not-working#)

ReactNative code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    AsyncStorage,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
const io = require('socket.io-client');

export default class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
        this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        const socket = io('http://localhost:3000', {
            transports: ['websocket']
        })

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log("socket connected")
            socket.emit('YOUR EVENT TO SERVER', {})
            socket.on('EVENT YOU WANNA LISTEN', (r) => {
            })
        })

        socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log("Disconnected Socket!")
        })
    }

    onPress(){
        // socket.emit('message', {data: 'data'});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', padding: 20}}>
                <Text>SOCKET IO</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{backgroundColor: '#EEE',  height: 50,  width: 200,  borderColor: 'black',  alignItems: 'center',  padding: 15}}
                    onPress={()=>this.onPress()}
                >
                <Text>CLICK</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

using this `const io = require('socket.io-client/socket.io');` in my case not work

and this is my dependencies from package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.2",
    "jest": "20.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
```

Comment: Do you have local socket server running?

Comment: Check the actual socket error, use console.logs to detect it

Comment: This is what console.log produces http://imgur.com/4KxgvSQ

Comment: Just a moment ago when my laptop connect over wify. and i connect my react native app to IP 192.168.3.110, it is connected. So it is only connect if my laptop connect to wify network. io('http://192.168.3.110:3000', {transports:['websocket']})

Comment: Have you tried using `ws://localhost:3000` instead of `http://localhost:3000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why, but in my case, `localhost:3000` does not work, I have to use the explicit IP address: `192.168.3.110:3000`.

Answer (score 3):

Localhost works well but remember one thing, every time you run `react-native run-android` don't forget to run *after that* also reverse mechanism `adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting up Laravel Echo using Socket IO with React Native and I also observed that my RN client is not able to receive the event from my Laravel server (using Homestead on Vagrant) if I used 'http://localhost' or in my case 'http://app.test'.  I had to use the IP address that I set in my Homestead.yaml file which is 192.168.10.10.

So in my RN App.js file is this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    window.io = require('socket.io-client');

    window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: 'http://192.168.10.10:6001'
    });

    window.Echo.channel('parking_session')
        .listen('TimeAlmostUp', (e) => {
            console.warn('Got event...');
            console.warn(e);
        });
}
```