# React Native - Cant get Simple socket.io Server to communicate with React Native Client

Tags: react-native, socket.io

Client:

```
      import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
  import io from "socket.io-client";
  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        chatMessage: "",
        chatMessages: []
      };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    this.socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
    
    console.log(this.socket);
    this.socket.on("chat message", msg => {
      
    console.log(msg);
          this.setState({ chatMessages: [...this.state.chatMessages, msg]   
      });
  });
  }

  submitChatMessage() {
    this.socket.emit('chat message', this.state.chatMessage);
    this.setState({chatMessage: ''});
  }
  render() {
    const chatMessages = this.state.chatMessages.map(chatMessage => (
      <Text style={{borderWidth: 2, top: 100, backgroundColor:'#e6e6e6'}}>{chatMessage}</Text>
    ));

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40, borderWidth: 2, top: 10}}
          autoCorrect={false}
          value={this.state.chatMessage}
          onSubmitEditing={() => this.submitChatMessage()}
          onChangeText={chatMessage => {
            this.setState({chatMessage});
          }}
        />
        {chatMessages}
      </View>
  );
  }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      height: 400,
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
  });

  export default App;
```

Server:

```
        const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const server = require("http").createServer(app);
    const io = require("socket.io")(server);
    const port = 3000;

    io.on("connection", socket => {
        console.log("a user connected :D");
        socket.on("chat message", msg => {
        console.log(msg);
        io.send("chat message", msg);
        });
    });

    server.listen(port, () => console.log("server running on port:" + port));
```

Can anyone see where im going wrong?

i Aslo found this that socket.io does not work on Android?

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505661/react-native-with-socket-io-doesnt-work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

You are trying to connect the socket in your mobile to a server on your mobile.

The localhost in your phone and in your computer are different.

Change the URL to the public id of your server.